# Print file name if grep finds multiple occurrences of a string in file, else exit on failure

Tags: grep

File1 contains

```
hello
hello
```

I need to write a grep command to print the filename if this file contains more than one "hello". Otherwise, I need grep to exit on failure.

So far I have

`grep -c "hello" File1 | grep -v :0`
but it outputs
`2`. How do I get the desired output, which should either be filename `File1` or no output at all (from what I understand, no match is a non zero exit code for grep)

Answer (score 2):

with GNU grep for `-z`:

```
grep -lz 'hello.*hello' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ seq 15 | grep -lz '3.*3'
(standard input)
$ echo $?
0

$ seq 5 | grep -lz '3.*3'
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: `grep -lPz 'hello\Rhello'` ;)

Comment: According to the man page `-P` is "experimental" when used with `-z`. I avoid it any time but especially with that warning!

Comment: So: `grep -lz $'hello\r?\nhello' `

Comment: I don't think it's required for the 2 "hello"s to be on separate lines, it doesn't say that in the question. If it were though then `grep -lz 'hello.*\n.*hello'` would be the way to do it.

Comment: I tend to avoid `\r?\n` as that'll mess up when trying to parse CSVs such as those exported from Excel where `\r\n` is a newline and `\n` alone can appear within fields. IMHO you should always know whether your newlines are `\n` or `\r\n` and if you don't then you have some programming choices to make :-).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

count=$(grep -c "hello" "$1")
if ((count > 1)); then
    echo "$1"
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Usage:

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh File1
```

Explanations:

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) in a shell:

```
perl -0 -le '
    my $filename = $ARGV[0];
    print $filename if grep { /hello\nhello/ } <>
' file
```